# Python: Decimal part of a large float

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the decimal part of `(pow(10, i) - 1)/23` for `0 < i < 50`. I have tried

```
(pow(10, i) - 1)/23 % 1
```

in Python 3 but I get `0.0` for all values of `i` greater than 17.

How can I extract the decimal part of a large integer in Python?

Comment: I guess you mean `float`, not `integer`?

Comment: If this is python2, `/` performs integer division (ie, `5/2 == 2`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To preserve precision, I'd probably use the [fractions](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) module:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(10)
Fraction(10, 1)
>>> Fraction(10)**50
Fraction(100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 1)
>>> Fraction(10)**50-1
Fraction(99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, 1)
>>> (Fraction(10)**50-1)/23
Fraction(99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, 23)
>>> ((Fraction(10)**50-1)/23) % 1
Fraction(5, 23)
>>> float(((Fraction(10)**50-1)/23) % 1)
0.21739130434782608
```

although using the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module would be another option.

update: wait, on second thought, the answer here is always going to be `((10^n-1) % 23)/23`, so the above is significant overkill (although it does scale up better to more complex problems).  We can even take advantage of the three-argument pow call:

```
>>> pow(10, 50, 23)
6
>>> pow(10, 50, 23) - 1
5
>>> (pow(10, 50, 23) - 1) % 23 # handle possible wraparound
5
>>> ((pow(10, 50, 23) - 1) % 23) / 23.0
0.21739130434782608
```

Answer (score 1):

One option that does not use other modules is

```
N = 10**i - 1
remainder = N % 23
print remainder / 23.0
```

Of course easily written on one line as well.

Using the [three argument form of pow](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#pow), which performs [modular exponentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), you can avoid large numbers alltogether, for improved performance.

```
((pow(10, i, 23) + 22) % 23) / 23.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean: "how can I extract the decimal part of a large **float** in Python? There is no "decimal" part anymore, because the comma is *floating*... :-)

On Python 2.7, for `i=20` (I divided by 23.0 in order to get a float result), the result is `4.347826086956522e+18`. There are 16 digits for a number of magnitude 10^18. Hence, there is no digit "after the comma" (this may be still incorrect für `i=20` because it could be that not all digits have been printed, but at least you get the concept of what I mean).

You have to apply a library that is implementing arbitrary-precision arithmetics for large `i`.